# Как обойти определение root прав на Android?

Tags: android, root

Есть программа, которая запрещает использовать root права, и запрещает использовать отладку местоположения. Можно как-нибудь обойти определения на устройстве root прав и отладку местоположения?

Comment: Скорее всего нет т.к закладывается все на более низком уровне

Answer (score 1):

Существует возможность скрыть Root, однако работает не на всех устройствах и не со всеми программами. Приложение называется [RootCloak](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.devadvance.rootcloakplus&hl=ru).